# Calling web service using phonegap(ios)

Tags: ios, web-services, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to call web services in phonegap application. I am using demo code given at

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/32513809/Simple-Web-Service-Consumption-with-PhoneGap-and-XUI

i have created xui.js from link

http://xuijs.com/downloads/xui-2.3.2.js

and tried both putting xui.js, index.html in www/assets and in www folder.

But it is not working for me.Can any one help me please.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding * to the ExternalHosts option in the PhoneGap.plist 
This may be the case if your app could not connect to the internet/make xhr calls

Comment: Hi guys i after solving this problem, i have written a blog about calling web services in PhoneGap http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/02/callling-web-services-in.html?

Comment: @ghostCoder, How about android, where do I have to fix. Getting exception because of cross scripting limitation. So where do i have to add that * to the ExternalHosts option in Android. Thanks.

Comment: there is no such thing for android. it should work as it is. what error are u getting

Comment: I am getting the message "`Put Stuff in Me`" as it is :(. It should have been replaced. When I tried using chrome I got `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=90210&maxRows=10. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` We used to get this error when accessing service hosted in other domain. I have used the same example, didn't change anything. All I have to do is something similar to the One you have mentioned for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Example:**

Use js to write this code and include in index.html file **Or** use javascript tag to write this code in html file.You have to include xui-2.3.2.js file in index.hmtl It is just for reducing the length of code.If u do not use this file then x$ will not work.

```
        x$.data = {};
        x$(window).load(function(e){
          x$("#returned_information").xhr("http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=90210&maxRows=10", 
            { callback: function(){
                var codes = eval("("+this.responseText+")").postalCodes; /* this should be an array */
                x$("#returned_information").html(codes[0].placeName);
              }
            }
          );
        });
```

and this in index.html body

```
      <h1 id="returned_information">
          Put Stuff in Me
      </h1>
```

At last give permission in property list file in External host to open the URL.
Add * in External Host Array.

I m sure it will work perfectly.