# Ajax request not working in Cordova/Phonegap iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, kendo-mobile

I am working on a Phonegap mobile app. Everything working fine in Android device but when I test on iOS device none of the web services working. I googled out and found that since iOS 9 they changed app transport security setting. In Info.plist file it also included as well. Anyone can help.

Comment: Maybe you have the same problem as  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379220/calling-web-service-using-phonegapios

Comment: Yeah I ready tested that but still having the same issue. Web services not working in iOS device.